# Mail merge - show line at empty cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010, mail-merge

I'm setting up an account list for a symposium. I'm using a simple excel document that merges to a word dokument. The word dokument is then to be printed so every user can sign his account. All the accounts are of the format `user.001` etc. Roughly half of the accounts also has a person tied to them, the rest will appear when the symposium starts.

Now I would simply have it that where the PersonName cells are empty, there should instead be a line to write your name by hand. So far I just filled every empty cell with a long line of underscore like this ______________________.

Is there a smarter way, like making Word detect empty cells and replace them with a line?

Comment: Are you planning this to become a paper document filled by hand (e.g., pen or pencil), or an electronic one, where they will edit the cell by themselves?

Comment: Yes. I thought that was made clear in both the first and second paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IF statement in the Name field. Something along the lines of

```
{IF {Mergefield Name} = "" "__________________________" "{Mergefield Name}"}
```

Note that the { } signs are not typed but denote Word fields. You can insert a field with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>F9</kbd>

Comment: Trying to do the same thing again but now it doesn't work anymore. It is as if the document can't recognize the field name. I get the FALSE expresion no matter what I do.