# IF statement with mail merge doesn't work

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010

I'm trying to recreate a mail merge in the way I specified in an old question [Mail merge - show line at empty cells](https://superuser.com/questions/567837/mail-merge-show-line-at-empty-cells)

However, now the formula doesn't work. The structure of the documents are as follows:
In the Excel-document there is a column called `PersonName`. What I want is the name to display if there is one and a line of underscores where the field is empty.
I have tried this formula:

`{IF {Mergefield PersonName} = "" "__________________________" "{Mergefield PersonName}"}`

with the result: `PersonName}`.

According to [this Microsoft site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/examples-of-if-fields-HP005187676.aspx), this is the correct syntax, but I can't get it to work.

I know that the fields are correct because the names that exist are displayed as they should. Should I write the syntax in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Late, but both the nested {Mergefield PersonName} fields need to be proper field codes - i.e. the {} need to be the special field code braces that you can insert using ctrl-F9, not the ones you type on the keyboard.

(If I create an IF field with the "ordinary {}", I get exactly the same result that you do.)